# NGINX : proxy_pass with regex and rewrite

Tags: nginx

i have this NGINX location in my `default.conf`

```
   location /api-gateway/ {
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
       proxy_read_timeout 100s;
       client_max_body_size 100m;
       proxy_set_header Host test.domain.com;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_buffering off;
       proxy_buffers 16 8k;
       proxy_buffer_size 4k;
       proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
       rewrite ^/api-gateway/(.*)$ $1 break;
       proxy_pass http://ingress-srv; # ingress-srv is an upstream
    }
```

here is an example of the request that is coming to my NGINX server: `http://demo.domain.com/api-gateway/service/v1/metrics`

i need to do the below

- remove the `/api-gateway/` from the original url and then,
- rewrite/send the requests to `ingress-srv` upstream without
  changing the URL (no redirect)
- change the header from `demo.domain.com` to `test.domain.com` which i believe i have done it correctly

i can not make it work ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
proxy_pass http://ingress-srv; # ingress-srv is an upstream
```

try doing (notice the slash):

```
proxy_pass http://ingress-srv/; # ingress-srv is an upstream
```

You can take out the `rewrite` directive.

As Oscar Wilde said "I was working on nginx.conf all the morning, and took out a comma. In the afternoon I put it back again."